# Complex derivative of a constant function should be $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\Bbb C\backslash\{0\}\to \Bbb C$ be a function defined by $$f(z)=\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})$$

I have verified that $f$ send the unit circle $U=\{z\in \Bbb C: |z|=1\}$ onto the segment $[-1,1]$. My question is, shouldn't the derivative of $f$ be ZERO on the unit circle given that the image of $f$ is line/segment/constant?

I found $$f^{\prime}(z)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2z^2}$$

but $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$ is on the unit circle and $$f^{\prime}(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt 2}{2})=\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{1}{2}$$

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: A function is called constant on $\Omega$ if and only if $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$ for all $z_1,z_2\in\Omega$. This is not the case here

Comment: So geometric intuition fails, a function whose image is a straight line along the $Re(z)$ axis is not necessarily constant? @MaximilianJanisch

Comment: if $\gamma $ is any differentiable curve such that $\gamma(t) \in U$ for all $t$ then $f \circ \gamma$ will have derivative zero.

Comment: If it was sent to a single point it would be constant, but as you said, it's into $[-1,1]$, where it can vary.. Further, it should be clear that $f(z) = \cos{z}$

Comment: @Kam How do *you* define “constant function”?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I confused the interval $[0,1]$ for straight line, on the real line, in other words, i conflated graphically constant in $x,y$ coordinates, and constant in any coordinates. The point is I was confused and now it is clear, thanks :)
Why did I get a downvote?

Comment: I don't know. I didn't do it.

Comment: @DaveNine I think rather $f(\exp(i z))=\cos(z)$

Comment: I knew you meant that @MaximilianJanisch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the real coordinate $x$, if the real function $f(x)$ is a horizontal line, then it is true that the derivative of $f(x)$ with respect to the real valuable $x$ is zero, i.e. $f'(x) = 0$.

However, this is not the case, or not comparable, in the complex coordinate $z$. If the complex function $f(z)$ is a horizontal line in the complex plane, then the imaginary component of $f(z)$ is a constant, i.e. $Imf(z)=const$. What can be concluded is only,

$$\frac d{dz}Imf(z) = 0$$

which is very different from stating $\frac {df(z)}{dz} = 0$. The confusion may have been a result of comparing to real functions.

Comment: thank you for clearing this up :)

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is not constant, as you say it sends the unit circle to the line segment.  For example,
$$ f(1) = 1 $$
and
$$ f(i) = 0 $$
So $f$ cannot be constant since there exists 2 inputs with different outputs, $f(1) \neq f(i)$